# Is there a way to throttle number of active threads with async/await? (degree of parallelism)

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, scheduled-tasks

I have an app that sends requests through network. Responses are retrieved by awaiting their `Task`s. There might be parent methods in the call stack which also use await. I don't want to limit how many requests might be sent but I want to throttle responses processing so that when thousands requests are suddenly completed at the same time my app won't run all their continuations at the same time. So I need a way to limit how many threads are used.

This code is a modified version from [MS LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-6.0). It attempts to limit active threads used by a task and all its children tasks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and the line after `Task.Delay` outputs that it runs on a default scheduler in a random thread. Is there a way to make it so that all children `await` are limited too?

The rules:

1. Children awaits is a library code, I can't modify them.
2. Only active threads, not tasks, should be limited. So `SemaphoreSlim` is not an option.
3. `ThreadPool.SetMinMaxThreads` is not an option, I don't want to change global settings.

   ```
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // Create a scheduler that uses 1 thread.
            LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            // Create a TaskFactory and pass it our custom scheduler.
            TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);

            var signal = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);


            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                int iteration = i;
                tasks.Add(factory.StartNew(() => TestAsync(signal.Task, iteration, 0)));
            }

            signal.SetResult(null);
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task TestAsync(Task signal, int iteration, int depth)
        {
            if (depth < 1)
            {
                await TestAsync(signal, iteration, depth + 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine(iteration + "." + depth + " method call await continued on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", scheduler = " + TaskScheduler.Current);
            }
            await signal.ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(1);
            Console.WriteLine(iteration + "." + depth + " delay await continued on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", scheduler = " + TaskScheduler.Current);
        }
    }

    // Provides a task scheduler that ensures a maximum concurrency level while
    // running on top of the thread pool.
    public class LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        // Indicates whether the current thread is processing work items.
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;

        // The list of tasks to be executed
        private readonly LinkedList<Task> _tasks = new LinkedList<Task>(); // protected by lock(_tasks)

        // The maximum concurrency level allowed by this scheduler.
        private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;

        // Indicates whether the scheduler is currently processing work items.
        private int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0;

        // Creates a new instance with the specified degree of parallelism.
        public LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        {
            if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxDegreeOfParallelism");
            _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        }

        // Queues a task to the scheduler.
        protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough
            // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another.
            lock (_tasks)
            {
                _tasks.AddLast(task);
                if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
                {
                    ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                    NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
                }
            }
        }

        // Inform the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed for this scheduler.
        private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()
        {
            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
            {
                // Note that the current thread is now processing work items.
                // This is necessary to enable inlining of tasks into this thread.
                _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
                try
                {
                    // Process all available items in the queue.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Task item;
                        lock (_tasks)
                        {
                            // When there are no more items to be processed,
                            // note that we're done processing, and get out.
                            if (_tasks.Count == 0)
                            {
                                --_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                                break;
                            }

                            // Get the next item from the queue
                            item = _tasks.First.Value;
                            _tasks.RemoveFirst();
                        }

                        // Execute the task we pulled out of the queue
                        base.TryExecuteTask(item);
                    }
                }
                // We're done processing items on the current thread
                finally { _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false; }
            }, null);
        }

        // Attempts to execute the specified task on the current thread.
        protected sealed override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            // If this thread isn't already processing a task, we don't support inlining
            if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems)
                return false;

            // If the task was previously queued, remove it from the queue
            if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
                // Try to run the task.
                if (TryDequeue(task))
                    return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
                else
                    return false;
            else
                return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        // Attempt to remove a previously scheduled task from the scheduler.
        protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
        {
            lock (_tasks)
                return _tasks.Remove(task);
        }

        // Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler.
        public sealed override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel { get { return _maxDegreeOfParallelism; } }

        // Gets an enumerable of the tasks currently scheduled on this scheduler.
        protected sealed override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            try
            {
                Monitor.TryEnter(_tasks, ref lockTaken);
                if (lockTaken)
                    return _tasks;
                else
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken)
                    Monitor.Exit(_tasks);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Have you actually encountered that problem or are you merely anticipating it?

Comment: Yes, I actually encountered it in another app where I had 60000 continuations running at the same time, filling entire `ThreadPool` and stopping all other work, even `Timer`s.

Comment: Regarding your example, does the `TestAsync` represents the library method that you can't change?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, simply - yes. If you want details I added a `depth` parameter to simulate the stack of several methods: some of them might be from my app but deeper levels are a library code.

Comment: Regarding the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` that is attached internally before awaiting the `TestAsync(signal, iteration, depth + 1)`, is it beyond your control to change it to `.ConfigureAwait(true)`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I can't change it to true (except in my app code but in a library code `ConfigureAwait(false)` is everywhere).

Comment: OK, I see. Personally I have nothing to add to Stephen Cleary's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164882/11178549). As a side note, you could replace the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` in your example with the built-in [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair), like this: `var lcts = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(TaskScheduler.Default, maxConcurrencyLevel: 1).ConcurrentScheduler;`

Comment: Another caveat. The `factory.StartNew(() => TestAsync(signal.Task, iteration, 0))` call in your example produces a nested `Task<Task>`. This is a task that represents the creation of another task. The outer task completes when the inner task is created, not when the inner task is completed. Most probably this is not what you want. Check out the method [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap), that returns a new task that represents the completion of both tasks (the outer and the inner).

Answer (score 2):

> Children awaits is a library code, I can't modify them.

If they use `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then you can't control the resulting context. You can provide a context (`TaskScheduler` or `SynchronizationContext`), but if the code uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then it will resume on a thread pool thread, and there is nothing you can do about it.

Your options are:

- Restrict what you *can* control. I.e., if you don't want to handle 6000 responses, then make less than 6000 concurrent requests.
- Increase the minimum thread pool count beyond what you will need.
- Do something insane like using profiling APIs to hook the internal methods that schedule continuations, and hijack them. Note that any such solution will depend on the runtime/BCL internals and may break without warning.

Comment: #1: requests might depend on a 3rd service which handles processing in batches. Having tens thousands of them may be a normal scenario until they all complete at the same time. Limiting them would just add unnecessary latency for a user.
#2: Increasing TP would lead to worsening overall throughput.

Comment: @Vlad: why do you say #2?

Comment: Context switching overhead